# Redux react native: how to properly call multiple actions from different reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, native, dispatch

In my react native / redux application I'd like to dispatch multiple actions.

I handle a list of elements in my app. With one reducer I maintain collections as a dictionary of {CollectionId : [ElementId1, ElementId2, ElementId3]. And in another reducer I maintain a dictionary of Elements {ElementId : {ElementName, ElementData, ...}}. This way the data is as normalized as possible.

Now if I want to delete all Elements from a specific collectionId, how do I dispatch the following two actions :

```
batch(() => {
    dispatch(deleteCollection(collectionId)) // removes the collection from the first reducer dictionary
    dispatch(deleteElements(Array<ElementIds>)) // removes all Elements 
}),
```

However I don't know the Array in advance, I only do have access to the collectionId. It's like the first dispatch should return the Elements Ids, so that I know what has to be further deleted in my second reducer.

My questions are: is it possible to return some value from a reducer action? Can I call my second action from within my first action ? Should I write all my logic outside of the reducers and only use the reducers as a way to modify the state, but compute how it would be modified from within a component or something ?

Comment: Does it have to be two actions? Why don't you just use one action `DELETE_COLLECTION` that deletes a collection and also remove elements of that collection? I mean, is there a case where you need to delete a collection and keep its elements?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the `arrayOfElementIds`. Also you need to delete the `Elements` first and then the collection.

**option 1 - assuming `deleteElements` and `deleteCollection` are asynchronous**

```js
// option 1 - assuming `deleteElements` and `deleteCollection` are asynchronous
const batch = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(deleteElements(collectionId)); // removes all Elements
};

const deleteElements = (collectionId) => async (thunk) => {
  // make api call and delete
  const arrayOfElementIds = await getCollection(collectionId);
  await apiService.post("/url", arrayOfElementIds);
  dispatch(deleteCollection(collectionId)); // removes the collection from the first reducer dictionary
};

const getCollection = (collectionId) => { // write a little helper to get the array of ids
  // make an api call or dispatch an action or something like that and obtain array of element Ids
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    res(["array of ids..."]);
  });
};
```

**option 2 - get the arrayOfElementIds from the store**

```js
// option 2 - get the arrayOfElementIds from the store using useSelector or mapStateToProps
const batch = () => {
  const arrayOfElementIds = useSelector(
    // get the arrayOfElementIds from the store
    (state) => state.ElementId.arrayOfElementIds
  );
  dispatch(deleteElements(arrayOfElementIds)); // removes all Elements
  dispatch(deleteCollection(collectionId)); // removes the collection from the first reducer dictionary
};
```

Comment: I like the ideas and they obviously work for something like deletion, right. But now if I also want to implement something like RemoveDuplicates() it doesn't help. If I want to remove duplicates I need to find duplicated elements, get their Ids, delete them and then pass those Ids to the collection reducer and delete those Ids from there as well